# Distinguishing local and remote access in shell (TERM-related)

Tags: ssh, terminal, shell, xterm

My default `TERM` is `xterm-color`. I would like it to be `xterm-256color` when I am working on my machine locally, but if I `ssh` to it I want to have it be `xterm-color`. How do I distinguish these two cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bash, in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $SSH_TTY ]]
then
    TERM=xterm-color
else
    TERM=xterm-256color
fi
export TERM
```