# tmux and screen-256 TERM not supported on remote hosts

Tags: ssh, terminal, colors, tmux

I have set up my tmux to use `screen-256colors` and it works great with vim.

However, when I ssh to a remote host from within tmux, `screen-256colors` isn't recognized, so I'm getting errors like this:

```
E558: Terminal entry not found in terminfo 'screen-256color' not known. Available builtin terminals are:
    builtin_ansi
    builtin_xterm
    builtin_iris-ansi
    builtin_dumb defaulting to 'ansi'
```

Other than editing each remote `.bashrc` (similarly to [this suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/251262/137732)), is there any way to set the `TERM` correctly and automatically on the remote host?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In most cases you need to install the necessary *terminfo* descriptions on the remote host. Terminfo is what Linux programs use to determine how to deal with a particular terminal (what control codes to send).

For example, on Debian or Ubuntu you usually need the `ncurses-base` package (which collects terminfo data for all "established" terminal emulators).

Failing that, you can manually copy the terminfo data for specific terminals:

1. On the local system, dump the description to text format:

   ```
   infocmp xterm-256color > xterm-256color.ti
   infocmp screen-256color > screen-256color.ti
   ```
2. Copy the files to the remote host and compile them again:

   ```
   tic xterm-256color.ti
   tic screen-256color.ti
   ```

On Linux, the descriptions will be stored in `~/.terminfo`. (Note that as of recent 2023 updates, this location will *not* be read by "setuid" programs anymore, although those are generally rare.)

`infocmp` and `tic` are part of the *ncurses* or *ncurses-bin* packages in most Linux distributions, as well as most BSDs that use *ncurses* (though on BSDs there might not be a per-user database).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and neat answer! I wish I could +2 this one

Comment: Agree. Worked like charm !

Answer (score 8):

I have this in my .bashrc:

```
alias ssh='TERM=screen ssh'
```